# Ajax datapost doesnt get trough to posted url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I am trying to post data to an php site which only contains php code which should be executed when the ID #mR-RateableFramePicture is being clicked on the first page. This is being done by a ajax request:

```
    $('#mR-RateableFramePicture').dblclick(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'moduleRateable/scriptSavedStyle.php',
            data: { rateableUserID: rateableUserID, rateablePictureID: rateablePictureID},
            success: function() {
                $('#DynamicContent').load('moduleRateable/scriptSavedStyle.php');
            }
        });
    });

    var rateableUserID = $('input[name="rateableUserID"]').val();
    var rateablePictureID = $('input[name="rateablePictureID"]').val();
```

And here the url destination which ajax posts to:

```
<?php
// Start the session (enable global $_SESSION variable).
session_start();

// Include database-link ($conn).
include '../../scriptMysqli.php';

// Make global variable to simple variable.
$userID = $_SESSION["ID"];

//Save the rateable style to one owns libary of saved styles.    
$ratedUserID = $_POST['rateableUserID'];
$ratedPictureID = $_POST['rateablePictureID'];


$sql = $conn->query("UPDATE styles WHERE userID = '$ratedUserID;' AND 
pictureID = '$ratedPictureID' SET savedByUser = '$userID'");

?>
```

I get the following error messages:

Notice: Undefined index: rateableUserID in C:\xampp\htdocs\mystyle\app\moduleRateable\scriptSavedStyle.php on line 12

Notice: Undefined index: rateablePictureID in C:\xampp\htdocs\mystyle\app\moduleRateable\scriptSavedStyle.php on line 13

Comment: Have you tried checking both on the client side (the request header sent) and on the server side (the `$_POST` global)?

Comment: i tried to display the variable rateableUserID with an alert inside the ajax request on the first page which resulted in the correct values being inside the javascript variables but like the error indicates, is there no $_POST variable being defined :/

Comment: try with `data: { "rateableUserID": rateableUserID, "rateablePictureID": rateablePictureID}`

Comment: @Niladri already in use, but doesnt work either :/ it seems like no data is coming trough.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing the value of the variables rateableUserID and rateablePictureID in your  `$.ajax({})` call like below -

`data: { rateableUserID: rateableUserID, rateablePictureID: rateablePictureID}`. Unless they are defined globally you will get undefined value at the PHP end.Make sure you have the value assigned to rateableUserID and rateablePictureID before you make the call. However still you have to check whether you are actually passing that variable in your post request or not because PHP cannot find the key name.

The function should be like below

```
$('#mR-RateableFramePicture').dblclick(function() {
     var rateableUserID = $('input[name="rateableUserID"]').val();
     var rateablePictureID = $('input[name="rateablePictureID"]').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'moduleRateable/scriptSavedStyle.php',
            data: { "rateableUserID": rateableUserID, "rateablePictureID": rateablePictureID},
            success: function() {
                $('#DynamicContent').load('moduleRateable/scriptSavedStyle.php');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to add my javascript variables, it's updated now :O

Comment: Even if it is undefined, the key should still exist and not throw a `index undefined` error. Because PHP basically receives the object as `{reteableUserID: undefined, rateablePictureID: undefined}`

Comment: I tried putting the javascript var inside the function but that doesn't seem to have helped either :/

Comment: @Johannes check what value are you getting by running the below in console `$('input[name="rateableUserID"]').val();` while debugging inside the function.BTW you are using double click to trigger the function and not single click.I dont know if thats your requirement.

Comment: When posting $('input[name="rateableUserID"]').val(); inside chroms console it returns the right value and the double with single click exchange broke the variable :( @Niladri

Comment: @Johannes updated my answer .. can you try passing the data as key value pair `data: { "rateableUserID": rateableUserID, "rateablePictureID": rateablePictureID}`

Comment: that didn't help either :/ @Niladri

Comment: @Johannes what about the double with single click exchange ?

Comment: var rateableUserID = $("input[name='rateableUserID']").val();
var rateablePictureID = $("input[name='rateablePictureID']").val();

I got this now but that doesn't change anything and having single clicks on both places breaks the variable and it doesn't contain any value anymore @Niladri

Comment: @Johannes no I was talking about just changing the `data` property of Ajax call like below `data: { "rateableUserID": rateableUserID, "rateablePictureID": rateablePictureID}` eveything else works fine on my side. see my updated code above

Comment: alright but those i changed too and nothing changed unfortunatly @Niladri

Comment: @Johannes this should remain as is `var rateableUserID = $('input[name="rateableUserID"]').val();`

Comment: @Niladri still the same :/